# Build KML with full namespace info from scratch with R's XML package

Tags: xml, r, namespaces

I write raster files to KML with KML {raster} and try to convert them with MAPC2MAPC for use on a mobile device.
However, MAPC2MAPC obviously is not working with these exported KMLs. I noticed that the only difference between the KMLs from my export and the one from Google Earth export (which are converted by MAPC2MAPC without problems) is the namespace definition. I then manually fixed the namespace in the kml and MAPC2MAPC was working. Now I try to fix the namespace programatically in R, without success.

The top node of a default KML looks like:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

the one of KML {raster} export like:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
```

I tried to parse the KML and add the namespace, making the second look like the first top node, but it didn't work..

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(XML)
# just a sample kml file... needs to be well-formed
z <-
  '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
      <Document>
         <Folder>
            <name>Some Name</name>
            <Placemark>
               <name>Jackson</name>
               <Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-91.151982,44.136728 -91.152627,44.158372 -91.152677,44.170618 -91.152732,44.183928 -91.152372,44.187182 -91.15244,44.187307 -91.152495,44.208702 -91.152892,44.222784 -91.153829,44.24758 -91.165786,44.247429 -91.165936,44.2546 -91.166159,44.272973 -91.166311,44.303743 -91.166469,44.306118 -91.166056,44.30943 -91.165995,44.33161 -91.16614,44.334932 -91.166128,44.335102 -91.16648,44.339077 -91.165909,44.343314 -91.166149,44.34968 -91.165604,44.37626 -91.165545,44.378794 -91.164813,44.418752 -91.164768,44.42248 -91.164873,44.451251 -91.164858,44.45132 -91.164915,44.451544 -91.165155,44.473148 -91.165187,44.480189 -91.165197,44.482528 -91.165636,44.496874 -91.1657,44.498476 -91.16588,44.509756 -91.165916,44.528032 -91.165696,44.550109 -91.165666,44.565612 -91.165408,44.567894 -91.165713,44.567989 -91.165619,44.596987 -91.130969,44.596692 -91.125674,44.596666 -91.119816,44.596285 -91.114632,44.596343 -91.043609,44.596609 -91.026595,44.596426 -91.009307,44.59663 -90.992352,44.596619 -90.990775,44.596447 -90.972986,44.596516 -90.94268,44.596582 -90.92235,44.596293 -90.922637,44.591081 -90.922579,44.580701 -90.922618,44.543798 -90.922775,44.512564 -90.923104,44.509838 -90.801852,44.509573 -90.80194,44.458502 -90.801949,44.429518 -90.801928,44.422301 -90.764289,44.422345 -90.760977,44.422336 -90.72215,44.422293 -90.719005,44.422213 -90.705154,44.422289 -90.680591,44.422218 -90.619465,44.422127 -90.558746,44.42221 -90.497221,44.422613 -90.436472,44.422546 -90.397588,44.423279 -90.31605,44.424673 -90.317397,44.337429 -90.31766,44.291998 -90.317938,44.249963 -90.318107,44.248791 -90.312035,44.248758 -90.31257,44.240933 -90.3125,44.194598 -90.312225,44.19244 -90.312083,44.187037 -90.31249,44.184046 -90.312575,44.155284 -90.435728,44.161022 -90.461889,44.16082 -90.488949,44.160944 -90.49033,44.16076 -90.546446,44.160284 -90.553421,44.160309 -90.591977,44.160163 -90.653047,44.159585 -90.672674,44.159319 -90.774673,44.159056 -90.792783,44.158862 -90.817517,44.158692 -90.817713,44.158644 -90.887873,44.158429 -90.888823,44.158484 -90.8929,44.158323 -90.906152,44.158316 -90.912893,44.154445 -90.916033,44.153313 -90.919834,44.150576 -90.922496,44.147593 -90.927157,44.14646 -90.930865,44.14648 -90.936741,44.147456 -90.939122,44.147337 -90.942552,44.144407 -90.945184,44.146673 -90.947547,44.147332 -90.948945,44.146008 -90.950352,44.143296 -90.952723,44.141954 -90.956902,44.141823 -90.958111,44.140704 -90.958909,44.137424 -90.962404,44.136491 -90.9641,44.137405 -90.966729,44.136248 -90.96894,44.133218 -90.97016,44.129621 -90.971909,44.128667 -90.976753,44.129869 -90.978639,44.127998 -90.978398,44.12666 -90.97364,44.124266 -90.971168,44.122493 -90.967644,44.119582 -90.968004,44.118533 -90.970286,44.117542 -90.973565,44.116895 -90.972764,44.070775 -91.023637,44.071134 -91.04639,44.071139 -91.057154,44.071141 -91.090641,44.071239 -91.091691,44.071192 -91.111766,44.071094 -91.151768,44.071014 -91.151843,44.079656 -91.151901,44.095396 -91.151975,44.114529 -91.151982,44.136728</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
            </Placemark>
         </Folder>
      </Document>
    </kml>'
xmlDoc <- xmlInternalTreeParse(z)

# this is the important bit...
ns <- c(gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2",
        kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2",
        atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
ensureNamespace(xmlDoc, ns)
# save it...
saveXML(xmlDoc,"sample.kml")
```

This adds the `gx:` and `atom:` Namespaces, but not the `kml:` Namespace (because it is already there). So I'm not sure if it will work on a mobile device but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a lot - haven't come across ensureNamespace() yet!!